# Is it possible to create a drawing, save it in such a format so then that drawing can be loaded back up?

Tags: processing

I am working on a drawing app in processing and wanted to know if it is possible to create a drawing and then somehow save that drawing into some format and then load that drawing back up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You can output it as an image using the `save()` function.

Or you could output the drawing in some other format. For example, if your drawing consisted of a bunch of lines, you could save them as a text file that contained start points and end points.

How you save your data is up to you, and what you need.

Check out the **input** and **output** sections of [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/) for some handy functions.

Good luck.